# Multiple textbox search from single database

Tags: php, html, mysql, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have 2 text boxes:

```
  <form action="adv-search.php" method="post">
    skill: <input type="text" name="skill"><br>
    Location: <input type="text" name="loc"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

I am using autocomplete mechanism for each text box (Data is fetched from Database)

When I click on the skill textbox, the column skill(present in `mytable` table) values must be retrieved automatically.

Similarly when I click on the loc textbox, the column loc(present in `mytable` table)  values must be retrieved automatically.

This can be easily done separately by using two separate tables. But in this scenario I am using a single table.

How can I proceed using a single table?

Comment: What you have tried so far? show some code

Comment: You don't need two tables, you just need two separate queries. Or you can even put both of them in one array and fetch only the needed.

Comment: "I Can Has Cheezburger" have told you everything you need to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here , you need to excute two separate queries,their is now issue even though you use same table for both the search.